# A simple error in perl using dbi

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi

I have a error in my prepare statement

```
$sqlst = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM starter_trot WHERE UserId = 2345' ) or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sqlst->execute($userid) or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $sqlst->errstr;
my @data;
print"hai";
while (@data = $sqlst->fetchrow_array())
{
print "**";
}
```

execute statement and prepare statement does not fail for sure.

[WHERE UserId = 2345]This is the part it fails.when i run the query in the db it retuns values.But when i run the query through scripts it fails (But no compilation or runtime issues)what is the problem.Is it in prepare we have to give with ?(bind variables and not actual values?)
~
~

Comment: Whats the entire error message?

Comment: Try adding \n to the end of your printed strings; perhaps the output is just being buffered?

Comment: No error message ..I am not getting the result set in the array....

Comment: How do you check that you do not get the result set in the array? Since you are *setting* @data for each row you get, a blank row could nuke your `@data`?

Comment: What happens if you **(a)** change the query to `SELECT 1234 FROM DUAL`, **(b)** remove the unneeded parameter from `execute()`, and **(c)** put _newlines_ at the end of every `print` call?

Comment: @TLP, what do you mean by "blank row?"  Do you mean a row of undefs (NULLs)?  That would not break the loop.  Do you mean end-of-records (in this case, no records found)?  That would break the loop.

Comment: @pilcrow Well, I'm not sure about the logic here, but something like `if (@a = undef) { print @a }` will still set `@a`.

Comment: It's probably the extra parameter to `execute`, but are you sure you're connecting to the same database in the code as on the command line?

Answer (score 3):

use strict, use warnings, and when using DBI, use RaiseError. You are executing with one bind value, when you have no placeholders in your SQL statement. Sure, you should see the error message the way you have it (since PrintError is the default), but RaiseError is easier than sprinkling 'or die ...' everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The DB is likely returning the column name as upper case.  Try:

```
$sqlst = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM starter_trot WHERE USERID = 2345' ) or        die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sqlst->execute($userid) or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $sqlst->errstr;
```

and I bet it will work.

Comment: My bad - it just occurred to me that it's when accessing the column names via fetchrow_hash that you have to refer to them in upper case.

Comment: Oracle doesn't care if you spell column/table names with upper or lower case. Unless you put quotes around them.

Comment: @runrig - Oracle doesn't but DBI does when fetching the data with fetchrow_hash.

Comment: I see no fetchrow_hashref in the OP. Nor any sort of fetching of column names. And the upper/lower casing of hash keys can be controlled with the FetchHashKeyName attribute (which it is generally best to always use when you fetch to a hash).